# what is the difference between multi-armed bandit testing with multivariate testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am learning A/B testing, and it says that sometimes A/B testing is not good enough to run the experiment so that we need to run multi-armed bandit, multivariate testing. Could someone help me understand what is the difference between multi-armed bandit and multivariate testing? does that mean they could be both used in the same scenario?

Thank you

Comment: I think you can find the answer in this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383798/multi-armed-bandit-vs-ab-testing), because in simple case ([full factorial design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_experiment)) you can think of Multi-variate testing as a standard A/B-test with multiple group A/B/../N.